# DD-WRT: How To Do Multiple APs on Wired Network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I've been following the page on the DD-WRT web page for linking routers as WAP's (wireless access points, both connected through a wired connection) [1], and I'm finding the following issues:

- I can't communicate with my second router reliably

  - Web admin/pinging doesn't always respond (timeouts)
  - The two routers flash activity like crazy after being plugged into each other (storming?)
  - WiFi clients have strong signal but terrible speeds (exhibits as starting/stopping downloads/etc)

Here's my setup:

- At present setting up 2 ASUS RT-N13UB1 DD-WRT flashed routers
- Gateway ASUS is 10.0.0.1, set up as AP as well as Gateway

  - Common settings:

    - WAN is active, set up as DHCP to my provider
    - DHCP server is enabled, clients served at 10.0.0.100-150
    - DNSMasq is used for DHCP/DNS
    - Set up in "Gateway" mode under Advanced Routing, no static routes
  - WiFi settings

    - Wireless Mode; AP
    - Wireless Network Mode: Mixed
    - Wireless SSID: Same as Secondary ASUS
    - Wireless Channel: 11
    - Wireless SSID Broadcast: Enable
    - Network Configuration: Bridged
    - Wireless Security Mode: WPA2 Personal, AES and same key
  - Secondary ASUS is 10.0.0.2, set up as AP, in router mode.

    - WAN & STP are disabled
    - Gateway is set to 10.0.0.1, as is local DNS
    - Assign WAN port to switch is checked
    - Advanced routing is set to "Router"
    - Dynamic Routing is set to "Disable", no static routes.
  - WiFi settings:

    - Wireless Mode: AP
    - Wireless Network Mode: Mixed
    - Wireless SSID: Same as primary ASUS
    - Wireless Channel: 6
    - Wireless SSID Broadcast: Enable
    - Network Configuration: Bridged
    - Wireless Security Mode: WPA2 Personal, AES and same key
  - Services:

    - DNSMasq is disabled, traff is disabled

Any help would be appreciated.  I'd love to extend WiFi coverage throughout our house.

[1] http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point#Long_Version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have solved this.  Here's the step-by-step in case anyone else has the same issue.

I enabled ssh and logging in dd-wrt, and remoted into the primary router (10.0.0.1).  Running tail -f /var/log/messages while trying to ping/access 10.0.0.2, I got a slow flood of messages looking like this:

```
Jan 30 07:47:38 pipes user.warn kernel: vlan1: received packet with  own address as source address
```

That looked suspicious - I looked at my LAN client tables and saw that no-one had the same *IP* address, but in closer detail, I saw that my router at 10.0.0.2 had the same *MAC* Address as my 10.0.0.1 device!

I fixed this by logging into my 10.0.0.2 device and enabled "MAC Address Cloning".  I chose a non-existent (made-up) MAC Address, and now I can ping/remote into it, and the routers aren't blinking like some 90's rave.

Hopefully that saves someone else.  I still have to verify that WiFi works, but I think this is on the right track.

Comment: If you ever find two networking devices that were both factory-programmed with the same MAC address, then you found a massive screwup on the part of that company.

Comment: Needless to say I won't be buying another ASUS router for a while. :)